# XStream fromXML for moved property

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream

Given a class Parent, which has been serialized to XML.

```
class Parent {
  Object A; 
  Child child;
}

class Child {
  Object C;
  ...
}
```

If the property C is moved from the Child object to the parent, as follows

```
class Parent {
  Object A; 
  Object C;
  Child child;
}

class Child {
  ...
}
```

For XML files made before the change, how do you make sure the child c tag populates the new property in the parent when deserializing with xstream?

Comment: I think when you are deserializing the xml, it was already generated, so it doesn't have this attribute defined on it, not sure, but i think it can't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are deserializing the xml, it was already generated, and a serialVersionUID was generated (it means if there is any difference in the class which was compiled again, another serialVersionUID will be generated), so it doesn't have this attribute defined on it, when you deserialize it and try to cast, it is going to throw an exception.

You will have to deserialize the two classes (Parent and Child) and set it on code like:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();

NewParent newParent = new NewParent();
OldParentWithoutC oldParent = (OldParentWithoutC) xstream.fromXML(xml);
OldChild oldChild = (OldChild) xstream.fromXML(xml);

newParent.setObjectC(oldChild.getC());
String xml = xstream.toXML(newParent);
```

Then you can serialize it again.

Comment: What about extracting just a single field from the XML? Is that possible to do with xstream? Will it require a custom converter?

Comment: I don't think so, but i'm not XStream expert, so maybe you can find you answer here: http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html But since you don't have a full object to serialize and deserialize it, its probably not going to work

Answer (score 0):

In general [object serializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) like [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) and [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) when converting an object of a certain class to an xml ([marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science))) it will save the class version code as well.

When the class is changed, so does the version code of the class.
In situations like this one the serializer tools as mentioned above will complain of the detected change and would not [unmarshal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) back avoiding fatal runtime errors.